# Can't commission node in MAAS due to "Failed to power on node" error

Tags: juju, maas

I have three nodes in my Maas, but when I select commission nodes it displays error:

```
ERROR    Tue, 10 Feb. 2015 11:33:08  Failed to power on node — Timeout after 7 tries

WARNING  Tue, 10 Feb. 2015 11:34:04     Failed to query node's BMC — Node could not be queried node-15d171e8-a6dc-11e4-8e2b-0030487c9128 (node1) invalid hostname
```

This is message from one node. Power mode is set to IPMI.

My hardware is two SuperChassis 808T-980V / 808T-980B with Intel Xeon e5345 2.33GHz and 16Gb DDR2-667 at 1333MHz

http://www.supermicro.com/products/chassis/1U/808/SC808T-980.cfm

Answer (score 2):

- Try adjusting your hardware clock.
- If you are using Cisco switches, try to enable Portfast.
- Try to `dig` and `ping` your fully qualified domain name of your node and make sure DNS and network connectivity are set right.